# VLC web-camera translation to vmware guest computer

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, webcam, vlc, broadcast

It is necessary to organize broadcast with a laptop camera to a virtual machine (I created a machine in wmare, organized a LAN - host-only. Network is working, cuz I can ping guest (OS Win8) and host(OS Win10) computers from each other), I'm using vlc project MSVS (cuz further I'll modify vlc player) - [Github](https://github.com/sunqueen/vlc-2.2.1.32-2013)  for translation. Broadcast is organized as follows:

> Stream -> Capture device -> select laptop's camera as video device name -> stream -> Http (as new destination), add -> Port = 8080, Path = "/" -> Activate
>   transcoding (Video - h.264 + MP3 (MP4) -> Stream.
>
> *Here generated stream output string:*
>   ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=auto,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/} : sout-keep "

As a result, when attempting to open url host on the guest OS in the same vlc project (also tryed open broadcast in Windows Media Player, no result), there is no broadcast. It freezes a little, some requests occures in wireshark, but then no broadcast. When I enable stream option "play video locally" on the host, it plays only 1 frame of the video (e.g. broadcast freezes). I tried to use vlc program (not github project? version 2.2.2) - the same result. Did anyone have similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helped for me: 1) added host's ip as "dst" in output string:

> ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=auto,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=**192.168.0.1**:8080}
>   :sout-keep"

2) Disabled NOD32 firewall